# Word Add-in: Change Word document body (as html) or replace

Tags: office-js, office-addins, office-store, word-web-addins

When writing an addin for Outlook, there are two APIs that allow one to change the html of the item:
`Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync` -> to get the html of the mailbox item
and another API to set the html:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync
```

What is the equivalent when writing a Word add-in (or Powerpoint addin).
I saw an API function to get the html of the document: `Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync`, or Word specific API which is [body.getHtml()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.body?view=word-js-preview#gethtml--)

But I only saw an API to set the selected area:

```
Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync
```

What am I missing? I simply want to be able to get the html of the document (or presentation), be able to change it as I want, and set it back.

Comment: Is `Word.body.insertHtml()` what you're looking for?

Comment: Aha, so the insertHtml actually can *replace* the html if passed with Word.InsertLocation.replace. The name of the function is a bit confusing.